# With image sliders on websites, is it bad to not allow user the option to manually control it?

Tags: website-design, buttons, interface, image

When implementing image sliders/carousels on websites, is it a necessity to put controls to allow the user to optionally click through the images if they desire, or is it okay to leave them transitioning in an infinite loop?

For more specific context, on the website I'm working on I plan to not have more than 4-5 images in the slider; if there were more images I could see the benefit of the controls, but for a small number of images (that don't link to other pages on the site) for display purposes only, is it acceptable to leave the option out?

Also, if you should add optional controls, when the user chooses to use them to go to another image, should you disable the automatic rotation, or leave it transitioning? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yeah though there are only 4 - 5 images but it will take a minimum of 20 secs to see the picture again once animation started.it will be irritating for the user to wait for such long times. **although the amount of content it has plays a major role**
so it is preferable to include carousel or scroll bar at the bottom so that he can see whatever he wants.
**you may want to animate the screens with picture transitions but you should provide controls with the user.**

> Also, if you should add optional controls, when the user chooses to
>   use them to go to another image, should you disable the automatic
>   rotation, or leave it transitioning?

you should allow the animation to run. Pause it only at times when the pointer is hovered over the image.

### Edit

It's one of the [10 Heuristics of User Interface Design](https://blog.prototypr.io/10-usability-heuristics-with-examples-4a81ada920c)

> **User Control and Freedom:**
>   This principle talks about giving the user the freedom to navigate and perform actions. The freedom to undo
>   any accidental actions. This principle can be best illustrated by the
>   Gmail’s flash message with undo action when we accidentally delete an
>   email.